# mysql order by specific column in random order with seed

Tags: php, mysql

good day.
i have 2 columns (product_id and total) and i need to randomize outup by specific column.

```
product_id   |   product_total  
    773      |   18
    840      |   22
    847      |   18
    888      |   20
```

i can order selection by RAND(123), however it randomizes by last selected column as i understand and in my case it is "Total". The suggestion found here to use

```
ORDER BY product_id ASC, RAND(123)
```

doesn't seem to work for me. 
how can i accomplish this?

***UPDATE***
I meant "specific" in my case random by product_id, because as i understand random output depends on what columns script randomize. this 2 queries give 2 different results:

```
SELECT p.product_id
FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
              WHERE p2c.product_id = p.product_id 
                AND p2c.category_id IN (92))  
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY RAND(123) LIMIT 0,15
```

and

```
SELECT p.product_id, count(*) AS product_total
FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
              WHERE p2c.product_id = p.product_id 
                AND p2c.category_id IN (92))  
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY RAND(123) LIMIT 0,15
```

**UPDATE2**
Two queries are identical except in first (lets call it Q1) `SELECT p.product_id` and in the second one (Q2) `SELECT p.product_id, count(*) AS product_total`
If i make a queries without `ORDER BY RAND(123)` i get for Q1:

```
product_id  
773
840
847
888
893
905
939
942
```

and for Q2:

```
product_id | product_total  
773          36
840          44
847          36
888          40
893          40
905          36
```

but with `ORDER BY RAND(123)` i get:
Q1:

```
 product_id     
1258
3226
2421
2146
2336
2228
3333
```

and Q2:

```
 product_id | product_total     
3154    34
3557    32
1749    34
960     34
1863    24
3389    38
2220    42
```

Results are not identical as you can see (by product_id). So the question is WHY?)

Comment: What is RAND(123) ? I think it should be RAND()

Comment: it is the $seed

Comment: `ORDER BY product_id ASC, RAND(123)` orders by product id. If, and only if, there is a tie (so you have a product id more than once), it orders by `RAND(123)` as a second criteria. I am quite certain this is not what you want to do, but on the other hand I am not entirely sure what you are trying to get ("randomize output by specific column"). Could you add a sample result? Or try just `ORDER BY RAND(123)`, it orders your rows randomly (well, with seed, so always the same way), maybe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Solarflare, i've updated post

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean by "random output depends on what columns script randomize". (If you want to keep explaining it, please do it with sample data). `ORDER BY RAND(335) limit 0,15` basically does the following: it adds a random value as a seperate column to the result you would get without limit and without order by. Then orders by that value. Then applies the limit. So try running your query without `order by rand` and compare. Does it give the same output? It might not, as the execution plan can be different (e.g. the 2nd left join is irrelevant for the 1st query).

Comment: upd2. I tried to explain as clear as i can and as my knowlege of English allow)

Comment: edited my post one more time because i got already confused too with queries. now it is like the output that i got. without RAND - output is the same except that in second query we join column Total, but when i add RAND with seed outputs differ

Comment: I'm unable to recreate the issue: http://rextester.com/UTOL59198 but note if I provide a seed to ran() I get the same order/results. if you use rand() you'd get different order/results between the two queries! so I agree that rand(123) is what you want if you want the same results as to why rand() returns different order, it's because a random seed is chosen for each execution.  Unlike @IngusGraholskis I think you want rand(123) so you get the same results.  the reason why they vary is because you don't have a constant seed.

Comment: The initial statement, "i have 2 columns (product_id and total) and i need to randomize outup by specific column."  makes no sense to me  you randomize the row among other rows, not a columns among columns.

Comment: of course i always use SEED, maybe i've wrote later here in post just RAND(), but it always with seed in fact!

Comment: xQbert, that is exactly what i want,
"
#these two will have the same order since we use the same seed on the rand()
Select * from SO46297707 Group by ID order by rand(123) limit 0,7;
Select ID, count(*) from SO46297707  group by ID order by rand(123) limit 0,7;
"
 but for some reasons my queries don't output the same results(( what can cause this?

Comment: I assume you are using 5.7? `rand()` works different than in rextesters 5.6 (the optimizer includes the value at a different point - sometimes resulting in bugs in 5.7). There's a warning in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) that rand in `order by` can be unpredictable. Also: your queries are different (the first one does not need to evaluate the left join to p2s), so you cannot expect them to work the same. You could try to use `select product_id from (your 2nd query including limit) x` to remove the column you don't want to get.

Comment: queries are identical except total selection, joins are the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried to make the simpliest queries

```
SELECT product_id, count(*) AS product_total
FROM oc_product_to_category p2c WHERE p2c.category_id='92' GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY RAND(335) LIMIT 0,15
```

and

```
SELECT product_id
FROM oc_product_to_category p2c WHERE p2c.category_id='92' GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY RAND(335) LIMIT 0,15
```

and the result was different. MySql ver 5.7.
I dont know if it is a bug or may be i missing something in using RAND() (with seed) func but the solution is to use all query as subquery without LIMIT and then RAND the result, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT product_id
    FROM oc_product_to_category p2c WHERE p2c.category_id='92' GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY product_id) AS T ORDER BY RAND(335) LIMIT 0,15
```

Alias here at the end is a must.